# can java return type write like Scala this.type

Tags: java, scala

I want to write some Java code like this in Scala

```
class A {
  def fun1(): this.type = {
    this
  }
}

class B extends A{
  def fun2(): this.type = {
    print("b")
    this
  }
}

object Test{
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    new B().fun1().fun2()
  }
}
```

but I can't, I think if the implicit *this* parameter of a method could be used for type inference, I can write like this:

```
class A{
    static <T extends A> T fun1(T t) {
        return t;
    }
}
```

the first parameter just like non-static method's first implicit *this* parameter.but this static method is not what I want.

Is there any way write like this without overriding from child Class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly you can't, because Types are handled on runtime in Java and can therefore not be used for more complex stuff (Like creating a new Instance, Array, checking what kind of type it is, ...)

A way that I like to use is this:

```
public abstract class A<T extends A> {
    public abstract T getType();
}

public class B extends A<B> {
    @Override
    public B getType() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

This ensures that you always have the "latest" class that extends your main-class which can then be used for pipelining or whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

this is very interesting question, so i wrote something like this. I don't think that this is in any way good approach to use in real life application, but this can be fun to watch.

```
public class A<T> {

    T fun1(){
        return getType();
    }

    T getType(){
        return (T)this;
    }

}


class B<T> extends A<T> {

    T fun2(){
        System.out.println("b");
        return getType();
    }

}


class C<T> extends B<T> {

    T fun3(){
        System.out.println("c2");
        return getType();
    }

}
```

And now hold on to something, beacuse it's getting weird. If you want to chain those methods you need to do something like this:

```
new C<C<C<C<C<C>>>>>().fun3().fun1().fun2().fun1().fun2().fun1();
```

Because of type erasure last fun1 will return Object.